# Trying to enter data in a form in Java before it goes to another form

Tags: java, forms

I have am trying to allow the user to fill in a form in Java after an error message has been displayed indicating that the field is empty. Currently the dialog boxes pop up and then the form goes directly to the next form with out allowing the user to enter anything.

Here is a snippet of the code I am working with:

```java
 private void btnEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

       //Confirming that the input fields have values
       String un = UserName.getText().toString();
       if(un.equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username Required");
       }

       String pw = Password.getText().toString();
       if(pw.equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Required");
       }

       //link to HRDBS
       HRDBS dbp = new HRDBS();
       dbp.setVisible(true);
       dbp.pack();
       dbp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       this.dispose();

    }
```

Thank you for your assistance with this matter

Comment: Looks like you should `return` after displaying each dialog.

Answer (score 0):

it will be a little better if the validation is moved to a separate method and returns on the first error. also you can accumulate errors in one message.

```
private boolean validateValues() {
    String un = UserName.getText().toString();
    if(un.equals("")){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username Required");
        return false;
    }


    String pw = Password.getText().toString();
    if(pw.equals("")){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Required");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void btnEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //Confirming that the input fields have values
    if(validateValues()) {
        //link to HRDBS
        HRDBS dbp = new HRDBS();
        dbp.setVisible(true);
        dbp.pack();
        dbp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```